# Select distinct and group by on subset of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, distinct

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I got stuck in this vicious circle between `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`

I've got the following dummy table `myTable`:

```
ID   Street         City          PostalCode   ProjectID   Date        NameId
1    Bar Street     Sunny Beach   666          7           25/08/2013  111
2    Sin Street     Ibiza         999          5           12/06/2013  222 
3    Bar Street     Sunny Beach   666          7           07/08/2013  333
4    Bora Bora      Bora Bora     1000         10          17/07/2013  444
5    Sin Street     Ibiza         999          5           04/07/2013  555
```

I want to obtain all records (probably first occurrence) with distinct Addresses(Street, City, PostalCode) and ProjectIDs.
For example the result here should be:

```
ID   Street         City          PostalCode   ProjectID   Date        NameId
1    Bar Street     Sunny Beach   666          7           25/08/2013  111
2    Sin Street     Ibiza         999          5           12/06/2013  222 
4    Bora Bora      Bora Bora     1000         10          17/07/2013  444
```

I've tried with `DISTINCT` on all columns, but this won't work, since `ID` is unique and always returns all the columns. Also tried `Group by Street, City PostalCode ProjectID`, but an error occurred regarding `Date` and `NameId`.

```
Column '' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

So how can I get a result, where a subset of columns are distinct?

Comment: Can you post the query that you tried?

Comment: If you want distinct records, why are you also outputting the ID and date fields? They differ between the records you're wanting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use the `row_number()` function:

```
select t.ID, t.Street, t.City, t.PostalCode, t.ProjectID, t.Date, t.NameId
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Street, City, PostalCode, ProjectId
                                order by id
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This is a window function that assigns a sequential value to rows with the same values in certain columns (defined by the `partition by` clause).  The ordering within these rows is determined by the `order by` clause.  In this case, it starts ordering with the lowest `id` in the group, so the outer query just selects the first one.

Comment: +1 for very good and understandable description for window function used.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this query

```
select myTable.*
from (select myTable.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Street, City, PostalCode, Projected
                                order by id
                               ) as rowid
      from myTable
     ) myTable
where rowid = 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba1b3/19)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with following query also  -

```
select * from myTable where id in
(
select min(id) from myTable
group by Street, City, PostalCode,ProjectID
)
```