# Select entries that have non repeating values on a specific column (although other columns may have repeating or non repeating values) (SQL)

Tags: sql

Let's say I have the following table:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | c1 | d1 |
| a1 | b1 | c1 | d2 |
| a2 | b2 | c3 | d3 |
| a2 | b2 | c4 | d3 |

I want to filter and see all four columns for entries that have the same value con column A but different on column C, so I get only this as a result:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a2 | b2 | c3 | d3 |
| a2 | b2 | c4 | d3 |

I don't really care if values con columns B and D are the same or different, although I would like to have them in my table to do further analysis later.

Using the `DISTINCT` statement would give me all the columns as a result, as they all are different in some column, so that doesn't work for me.
I read some questions ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186379/select-distinct-and-group-by-on-subset-of-columns)) and the answers recommended using the `row_number() over(partition by...)` clause, although the use they gave it doesn't quite fit my problem (I think), as it would also return the first row with a repeating value on column C.

Any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: Where are your attempts?

Comment: You can simply join the table with itself, e.g. calling it Table_1: `select T1.* from Table_1 T1 join Table_1 T2 on T1.a=T2.a and  T1.c!=T2.c `

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.a = t.a and t2.c <> t.c
             )
order by t.a;
```

Comment: And what if table t is the result of ```t_a JOIN t_b ON ...```, how can I give it an alias such as t2?

Comment: @Francisco . . . (1) That would be a different question.  This question starts "Let's say I have the following table:".  (2) You can use a CTE to define `t`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `self join`

```
select t1.*
from t t1
join t t2 on t1.a=t2.a and t1.c<>t2.c
```